# How works URLENCODE for params in curl PHP?

Tags: php, curl, telegram, telegram-bot, urlencode

I have very strange problem with `urlencode` and now i explain:

I have a telegram bot the send a message to me with url, so for this reason i want to add `urlencode` fot text that i will paste in url.

But if use `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` i have the strange problem.

---

The message to send is:

```
  This is an example my friend
```

But if use `urlencode` and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` the output is:

```
  This+is+an+example+my+friend
```

---

**Now i show the full code:**

```
$notifica= urlencode("This is an example my friend");
sendMessage(xxx, $notifica);
sendMessage_2($notifica);


function sendMessage($chat_id, $message){           
   $params=[
    'chat_id' => $chat_id,
    'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
    'text' => $message
   ];

   $url= 'https://api.telegram.org/botxxx';
   $ch = curl_init($url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS, 3500);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 3500);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch); 
}

function sendMessage_2($mess){          
    $url= 'https://api.telegram.org/botxxx/sendMessage?chat_id=xxx&parse_mode=HTML&text='.$mess;

    $ch = curl_init();  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS, 3500);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 3500);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);    
}
```

I hope someone can help me...
thanks a lot and sorry for my english

Comment: What's your question? `+` is the way that spaces are encoded in URL parameters.

Comment: You don't need to call `urlencode()` yourself. When `$params` is an array, `curl` automatically encodes it.

Comment: wow i didn't know that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `urlencode()` when you're putting the parameters in an array with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. The [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) says:

> If `value` is an array, the *Content-Type* header will be set to *multipart/form-data*.

This format doesn't require URL-encoding, so the server won't automatically decode it. As a result, the characters used in the encoding (space is encoded as `+`, other special characters use `%` followed by hex codes) will be treated literally.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));`

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.